# focus on input text

Tags: actionscript-3

When I put focus on input text, I get Error #1023.
Any help?

```
mc.tabChildren = true;
mc.tabEnabled = true;
mc.getInputTxt().tabIndex = 0

mc.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN,updateFocus);

private function updateFocus(e:FocusEvent):void{
stage.focus = e.currentTarget.getInputTxt()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack overflow, infinite loop.

```
if (stage.focus != e.currentTarget.getInputTxt())
    stage.focus = e.currentTarget.getInputTxt();
```

Or:

```
if (e.target == e.currentTarget.getInputTxt())
    return;

stage.focus = e.currentTarget.getInputTxt();
```

Comment: It didn´t work.
I´ve tried both.
I think it´s about a flash component TextInput. It has some draws (maybe movieclips).
Error #1023: 
 at fl.core::UIComponent/getDisplayObjectInstance()

There´s alot after that, but it doesn´t fit in the comment

Comment: I´ve got it. 
I must set the mc whom has the input text component tab index

Comment: @MarceloNoronha How about `if (e.target != e.currentTarget) return;`? A full stack trace would help.